# Auction of mortgaged properties during bankruptcy

Tags: house-rules, monopoly

We have a house rule - **No form of trade/deal is allowed between players. If someone wishes to sell anything - an auction has to be held always and the property goes to the highest bidder.**

There are 3 players in the game. One player lands on my property and has to pay me rent but has no cash and all his properties have been mortgaged. **Is he allowed to hold an auction for his mortgaged property to gather cash to avoid bankruptcy?**
(officially I know under standard rules he could have made trades with the 3rd player to avoid bankruptcy but that is not possible)

I am inclined to think that since the bank bars us from collecting rent on the mortgaged properties an auction of mortgaged properties also doesn't make sense to me.

So to summarize - **Can the player who is about to go bankrupt - legally put his mortgaged property card at the center of the board and hold an auction?**

Comment: To be fair, you're asking about the game prefaced with your house rule and asking us how that house applies in a specific situation... that's not really something we can answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question.

> Can the player who is about to go bankrupt - legally put his mortgaged
> property card at the center of the board and hold an auction?

Short answer from **Hasbro**:

**... it is illegal to auction off property when someone owes another player.**

Long answer, from **Hasbro**'s Global Consumer Care Representative

**Note.** Hasbro own the copyright on Monopoly and are therefore the ultimate authority on rules in the game.

> Yes, it is illegal to auction off property when someone owes another
> player.
>
> **Try to raise money.** If you owe money and can't pay, try to raise money by selling buildings back to the Bank and/or mortgaging
> properties.
>
> **Selling Buildings** Sell Hotels to the Bank for half the cost price and exchange them immediately for 4 Houses. Sell Houses to the Bank
> for half the cost price. Houses must be sold evenly across the colour
> set.
>
> **Mortgaging Property** To mortgage a property, you must first sell all buildings in its colour set to the Bank at half their cost price.
> To mortgage, turn the Title Deed card face down and collect the
> mortgage value on the back from the Bank.   To repay a mortgage, pay
> the unmortgage cost to the Bank (mortgage value +10%); then, turn the
> card face up.
>
> **If you're still in debt, you are bankrupt and out of the game!**
>
> **Do you owe another player?** Give them any Get Out of Jail Free cards you have, and all your mortgaged properties.   The new owner
> must immediately either:
>
> - repay the mortgage (pay the Bank the unmortgage cost), or
> - keep the mortgage (just pay the Bank 10% of the mortgage value now).
>   **Do you owe the Bank?**
>
> Return all your properties to the Bank.
>
> Any mortgages are cancelled.
>
> All your properties must immediately be putup for **auction.**
>
> Return any Get Out of Jail Free cards to the bottom of the pile.
> The remaining players keep playing until there is only one person left in
> the game - the winner!
>
> Again, I'd like to thank you for taking the time to reach out to us.
>
> I hope you have a fun day!
>
> Kind regards,
>
> Rochonda Global Consumer Care Representative
>
> Customer By CSS Web (Robert Miller) (08/26/2020 02:24 PM)
>
> Hello,  Is it legal for a player who is facing bankruptcy to another
> player, to auction off his properties in order to avoid bankruptcy?
>
> Question Reference #200826-000598 •   Date Created: 08/26/2020 02:24 PM • Date Last Updated:
> 11/10/2020 06:13 PM • Status: Solved [---001:001949:01623---]

Comment: This might be correct, except the question is about how things function under the house rules Rishabh plays by, once house rules go into the game, the printed rules and the rulings on them at least partially go out the window. Your answer seems to ignore the premise of the question completely.

Comment: I kind of agree with Robert here. I just made 1 small house rule(control the way in which trades occur) - the printed rules "can't go out of the window" @Andrew. So if from Hasbro - "it is illegal to auction off property when someone owes another player" I think that clearly solves my question.

Answer (score 6):

**Since the "no trading/selling" rule is your own house rule, you're going to have to determine this yourself.**

My own opinion is that you should probably allow the auctioning off of mortgaged property.

Why? Because the only thing the standard rules say you can't sell is *improved properties* (property with houses/hotels). It explicitly allows the selling/trading of mortgaged property, after which the "interest" on the mortgage comes due.

From [the offical Hasbro rules book](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf) (pdf):

> **SELLING PROPERTY**… Unimproved properties, railroads and utilities (but not buildings) **may be sold to any player as a private transaction for any amount the owner can get**; however, no property can be sold to another player if buildings are standing on any properties of that color-group.

and later under "Mortgages":

> The player who mortgages property retains possession of it and no other player may secure it by lifting the mortgage from the Bank. However, **the owner may sell this mortgaged property to another player at any agreed price**. If you are the new owner, you may lift the mortgage at once if you wish by paying off the mortgage plus 10% interest to the Bank.  If the mortgage is not lifted at once, **you must pay the Bank 10% interest when you buy the property** and if you lift the mortgage later you must pay the Bank an *additional* 10% interest as
> well as the amount of the mortgage.

So since your "bank auction" is your house-rule substitute for selling directly, it only makes sense to maintain the same conditions, and allow auctioning of mortgaged property.

Comment: I agree with this.. the house rule seems to pretty much just place a restriction on *how* a sale/trade is to be negotiated. It would be a separate though related house rule to also place a restriction on *what* items can be sold/traded.

Comment: Doesn’t allowing auction of mortgaged property during bankruptcy stretches the game to be extremely long.  When this bankrupt guy holds an auction -1. If I take part in the auction I end up either paying my own rent or more than my own rent. 2. If I don’t take part in the auction and if 3rd party gets the property for say 1$ it’s always a lose lose for me. So it’s kind of like my bad luck that the player lands on my property

Comment: @RishabhBaid That's not much different as under normal rules - he could make a quick side deal to sell a property to a different player to pay his debt, or he can make a deal with you to include property as part of the payment. Either way you get your money, and he's down a property. If you prevent him from auctioning a property to raise money in that moment is a fine house rule, but it is a pretty big change.

Comment: @BradC the key words I am stressing on are ‘mortgaged’ ‘auction’ and ‘bankrupt’. Like in real life I want to understand - I mortgaged my property - bank gave me loan - in the event of default - bank auctions my property- and generates revenue. Now when I have defaulted can I ask the bank give me sometime - “I will auction this property and after repaying you will keep the remaining profit”. I believe there is a conflict of interest between me and the bank if I officially hold an auction of mortgaged properties when I am bankrupt (I have nothing else except the mortgaged property)

Comment: @RishabhBaid ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ You're entitled to make your house rules whatever you want, I just don't think there is any *inherent* connection between your existing "we auction property instead of selling/trading directly" house rule and your (proposed in this question) "you also can't auction mortgaged property in the moment when you need it most" rule.